# While loop for user input of a value between 1000-10000

Tags: function, while-loop, pygame

Trying to make it so if the user does not enter in an amount from 1000-10000 they are asked the question again. This is what I have so far, but it still just updates the text on the pygame window regardless of what I put in for the user input.

```
balance_value = int(input('How much would you like to start with? Choose from $1000-$10000: '))

def side_text(x,y):
while not (balance_value >= 1000 or balance_value <= 10000):
    int(input('How much would you like to start with? Choose from $1000-$10000: '))
if balance_value >= 1000 or balance_value <= 10000:
    money = font.render('Balance: '+ str(balance_value), True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(money, (x,y))
```

Comment: It seems to me to don't do anything with the return value of your `input` call

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the input back to `balance_value`:

```
balance_value = int(input('How much would you like to start with? Choose from $1000-$10000: '))
```